# Start Node.js Server from Website

Tags: node.js

I was wondering if I could dynamically start a Node.js server from a website in PHP or JavaScript. I want to create a website where a user can create a server that can be connected to by an app, so I want to be able to click a button on the website and have it start a server (maybe even picking a random open port).

Comment: yes.           (15 chars limitation fix)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one web server can, on behalf of some user of that web site, start another web server.  If the two web servers are on the same IP address, then they would have to be on different ports since you can only have one server listening to a given port at a given IP address.

The flow would be something like this:

1. User A goes to webpage on Website A
2. User A presses button on webpage for Website A to start new server
3. webpage sends a command to Website A's server (either a form submission or an ajax call or a link)
4. server on website A receives the command and does any validation/credential checking required
5. website A issues OS-level command either on local server or on some other server that it is connected to to start web server B
6. User A can now connect to web server B

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about sending the command. I would have one website running on an Apache web server and it should be able to start an unlimited number of Node.js web servers on the same Linux box. In case you are curious, I am using Ubuntu 14.01 on a DigitalOcean Droplet.

Comment: @nrubin29 - One might ask why you want to run N node servers rather than one server that serves all the users?  And how do you propose to allocate different port numbers to each node server?  And how will each client browser know which port to use?

Comment: I am making a program that allows teachers to create quizzes and host them to students using a desktop program or app. I wrote the teacher and student applications using Java but then I discovered Node.js and said to myself: "Hey, I could rewrite the teacher application as a website and have it host the quizzes for the desktop app (or website) to use" - Self.

Comment: @nrubin29 - it sounds like you should have one server that serves multiple quizzes, each with its own URL.

Comment: I have looked into executing commands with PHP, but I cannot find a way to run commands in the background and be able to get input. In Java, I can create a new thread and write messages to `stdio` as I receive them. Can I do this with PHP somehow?

Comment: @nrubin29 - What does "run commands in the background and get input" mean?  Please describe more specifically what you are trying to do.   Your question just says "start a server" - it doesn't describe anything more than that.

Comment: I would like to use the `node` command to start a `node.js` server like this: `node file.js`. I would also like to have access to anything the server outputs, like `Server Started` or `{User} joined.` Unless there is an easy JS trick to start the server, I would need to use the command with the command line. I need to have the server running in the background, but it needs to be able to modify the open page (user joins, add their name to a table; message sent, popup the message, etc.)